# How can I remove the close button in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3, winui

How can I remove the close button in WinUI 3?

Screenshot of WinUI 3 App

[image: 1]

Comment: Title Bar Customization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar but only for Windows 11+

Comment: AFAIK, you can't customize caption buttons (for the moment at least). That area is a reserved area. The closest way that I can think of is to HIDE caption buttons by making your window Full Screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the winui framework didn't provide relevant API. But we can do this indirectly.

When `this.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;` ,
**The top-right corner menu buttons(max,min and close) are simulated with common winui elements.** This could be observed in Debug->Windows->Live Visual Tree tool window. Here is a screenshot of my program.
[Visual Tree ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KveG.png)

Notice that the root element we declare in Window xaml file is the child of `ClientAreaPresenter`. And the simulated buttons are under `TitleBarMinMaxCloseContainer`.

So, what we need to do is

1. Obtain the close button element using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()`
2. Set its `Visibility` property to `Visibility.Collasped`. (But this may not look good. I personally suggest hide all the buttons at the same time).

Here is the sample code works for me.

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true; //Hides the default system titlebar.
    }

   //Visual tree may not have been loaded yet at Ctor. 
   //It's suggested registering Loaded event of the root element of the window.
    private void RootGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets the close button element. Refer to the Visual Tree.
        var contentPresenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this.Content);
        var layoutRoot = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(contentPresenter);
        var titleBar = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(layoutRoot, 1) as Grid;
        var buttonContainer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(titleBar, 0) as Grid;
        var closeButton = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(buttonContainer,2) as Button;
        if (closeButton != null)
        {
            closeButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Hides the button.
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to hide all the menu buttons, then change the `Visibility` property of the `buttonContainer`. It also works by setting its `RenderTransform` to make it out of the window render area.

[Window with close button hidden effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNvds.png)

**However this method is not documented, so its compatibility depends on the framework visual tree implementation. In some cases the app can throw an exception on window closing.**

Comment: When hiding all the titlebar buttons, it's recommended that you use `RenderTransform`  instead of `Visibility`, as Visibility.Collasped cannot prevent clicking the buttons sometimes. `titleBar.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform() { X = 200 }` (titleBar here is the element previously obtained)

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with WinUI 3, I cannot only remove the close button, however, it is possible to hide the whole title bar area.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;

namespace WinUI3
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            GetAppWindowAndPresenter();
            _apw.IsShownInSwitchers = false;
            _presenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
        }

        private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myButton.Content = "Clicked";
            this.Close();
        }

        public void GetAppWindowAndPresenter()
        {
            var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
            WindowId myWndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
            _apw = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);
            _presenter = _apw.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;
        }
        private AppWindow _apw;
        private OverlappedPresenter _presenter;
    }
}
```

This piece of code will create a window without title bar (minimize button, maximize button and close button).